# Return error message from a void method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, error-handling

I'm currently trying to get my method to return an error message if a condition isn't valid. But I am uncertain how to go about this in a void method.

I have a method that looks like this

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Audit]
        public void AddUnits(int so_id, int site_id, int[] addItem_id, int[] addItem_qty, int[] addItem_disc)
        {
            // Loop however many times is necessary to iterate through the largest array
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(Math.Max(addItem_id.Length, addComp_id.Length), addPart_id.Length); i++)
            {
                foreach (SODetails sod in db.SalesOrders.Find(so_id).SalesDetails)
                {
                    if (i < addItem_id.Length && addItem_qty[i] != 0 && sod.ItemID == addItem_id[i] && addItem_id[i] != 365 && addItem_id[i] != 410) 
                    {

                        sod.item_qty += addItem_qty[i];
                        sod.item_discount = addItem_disc[i];
                        addItem_id[i] = 0;
                        addItem_qty[i] = 0;
                        addItem_disc[i] = 0;
                    }              
                }
                db.SaveChanges();

                if(i < addItem_qty.Length && addItem_qty[i] != 0)
                {
                    SODetails sODetails = new SODetails
                    {
                        SalesOrderID = so_id,
                        SiteID = site_id
                    };
                
                    // Only add a unit to the SODetails object if it's not null and has an id and quanitity specified
                    if(i < addItem_id.Length && addItem_id[i] != 0 && addItem_qty[i] != 0)
                    {
                        sODetails.ItemID = addItem_id[i];
                        sODetails.item_qty = addItem_qty[i];
                        sODetails.item_discount = addItem_disc[i];
                    }
                
                    if (sODetails.SiteID == 0)
                        sODetails.SiteID = null;

                    
                    SalesOrder SO = db.SalesOrders.Find(sODetails.SalesOrderID);
                    SODetails salesOrderDetails = db.SODetails.Add(sODetails);
                    salesOrderDetails.SalesOrder = SO;

                    Item SO_Item = db.Items.Find(sODetails.ItemID);
                    Component SO_Component = db.Components.Find(sODetails.ComponentID);
                    Part SO_Part = db.Parts.Find(sODetails.PartID);

                    if (SO_Item != null)
                    {
                        if (SO.OrderType == SOType.OffSiteInventory && sODetails.InventorySite == "Main Inventory" && SO_Item.On_Hand < salesOrderDetails.item_qty)
                        {

                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Not enough stock in inventory");
                                //TempData["SalesOrderMessage"] = SO_Item.SalesOrderMessage;

                        }

                        sODetails.item_qty = sODetails.item_qty == null ? 0 : sODetails.item_qty;
                        int qtyOrdered = sODetails.item_qty == null ? 0 : (int)sODetails.item_qty;
                        salesOrderDetails.dynamicItem_qty = qtyOrdered;

                        if (SO_Item.SalesOrderMessage != null)
                            TempData["SalesOrderMessage"] = SO_Item.SalesOrderMessage;
                    }

                    db.SODetails.Add(sODetails);
               
                }
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Here is the part of the code where I am doing the validation check

```
 if (SO.OrderType == SOType.OffSiteInventory && sODetails.InventorySite == "Main Inventory" && SO_Item.On_Hand < salesOrderDetails.item_qty)
                        {

                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Not enough stock in inventory");
                                //TempData["SalesOrderMessage"] = SO_Item.SalesOrderMessage;

                        }
```

If the condition is valid I want it to return to the screen with an error message showing up. But with the method being Void, I don't know how I can make it do this, or I don't know if it is even possible.

Comment: You can throw an exception and add a mechanism to handle the exception and display the error on your UI.

Comment: You could throw an exception and handle it at the UI by displaying it's message.  Otherwise you'll have to change to returning some type of status.

Comment: ASP.Net MVC action methods shouldn't be `void`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a specific exception class that you can throw in your void function. You then handle this exception in the calling function.

```
class NotEnoughStockException : Exception {}
```

Then in your method:

```
If no stock ...
    throw new NotEnoughStockException();
```

In the calling method

```
try {
     call the stock method
 } catch NotEnoughStockException {
     whatever you want to do
 }
```

Create a wrapper function that will call your stock function. You do  try catch in that new function and return an error message. Your Ajax should call the new function.

Comment: It's an ajax function that calls it. And when I put the try catch around it nothing happened. Maybe I'm not understanding correctly